# Understanding recursion in λ calculus

Tags: computer-science, formal-systems, lambda-calculus

1. In [recursion for λ calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Recursion_and_fixed_points), I was wondering why the following two are equal

   > (λx.g (x x)) (λx.g (x x))
   >
   > g ((λx.g (x x)) (λx.g (x x)))
2. How shall I understand g ((λx.g (x x)) (λx.g (x x)))?

I am learning λ calculus from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), and I can understand many of its basics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you evaluate $(\lambda x.g(x x)) (y)$, it is equivalent to $g(y y)$ (This is called $\beta$-reduction). Therefore, when you do
$$
(\lambda \, x.g(x \, x))(\lambda \, x.g(x \, x))
$$
You can see the second parenthesis as the "big chunk you're putting as an argument in your abstraction on the left", so that
$$
(\lambda \, x.g(x \, x))(\, Y \,) \quad \underset{\beta}{\rightarrow} \quad g(\,Y \quad Y\,) \quad \rightarrow \quad g( (\lambda \, x.g(x\, x))  (\lambda\, x.g(x \,x)) )
$$
(I used the right-arrow to say "reads as". This is standard for $\beta$-reduction.)

Wikipedia is not a place to learn, it's a reference. You should use it only to take a look at fun stuff or recall something you've already learned. For learning, you should use books or tutorials, it's a better idea. Try this as a tutorial :
http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps112/Spring03/readings/lambdacalculus/introduction.html

Hope that helps,